# msbuild adding items to "Source Files"

Tags: c++, msbuild

I want to allow in my project template (c++) to add files with specific extension ".myext" and in msbuild I'll find the suitable header and ".cpp" files and add them accordingly to the  and to  but I need also to add these files to the "Source Files" filter after adding the items with the ".myext" extension.

this is how I find the files and add them accordingly :

`<Target Name="FilterMyFiles">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Filtered Include="@(None)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.myext'" />
    <SourceFiles Include="@(Filtered->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename)_source.cpp')" />
    <HeaderFiles Include="@(Filtered->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename)_header.h')" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="%(HeaderFiles.Identity)" Condition="Exists('%(HeaderFiles.Identity)')" />
    <ClCompile Include="%(SourceFiles.Identity)" Condition="Exists('%(SourceFiles.Identity)')" />
  </ItemGroup>
  </Target>`

I tried to add some changes to the msbuild file (".vcxproj") and to the filter file (".vcxproj.filter") but nothing helped.